# A probability question (outcomes)

Tags: probability

John has $\ 6 $ coins. He performs a test which involves tossing all coins simultaneously. He repeats this experiment until all coins shows up as heads. What is the probability that it takes him at least $\ 12 $ tosses to achieve this feat?

Comment: Until all coin shows up heads at least one or simultaneaously?

Comment: Hint: it requires at least 12 repetitions of the experiment if and only if each of the first eleven experiments resulted in at least one of the coins showing a tail.

Comment: Hint: Think of the geometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The probability to fail at any toss is $p=1-\frac1{2^6}$ (why?). 
The probability of failing $11$ times in a row is $p^{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of having all $6$ coins come up heads simultaneously on any given throw is $(1/2)^6 = 1/64$

The Geometric Distribution is used to determine the number of Bernoulli trials needed to get $1$ success.  What we are seeking here is the probability that a series of Bernoulli trials with probability $1/64$ takes longer than $12$ trials to achieve a success.

The cumulative distribution function for the Geometric distribution is $1 - (1-P)^k$, where $P$ is the probability of success and $k$ is the number of trials.  The table below is computed by substituting $1/64$ for $P$ and the value in the first column for $k$.

$k$      $P(n\le k)$
$1$      $0.0156$
$2$      $0.031$
$3$      $0.046$
$4$      $0.061$
$5$      $0.075$
$6$      $0.090$
$7$      $0.104$
$8$      $0.118$
$9$      $0.132$
$10$      $0.145$
$11$      $0.159$

The bottom line tells us that there is approximately a $15.9\%$ chance that we will have a success by the $12$th trial.  Therefore there is approximately and $84.1\%$ chance that it will take at least $12$ tries before getting all $6$ coins to show heads.